# Rollback on \include error in psql

Tags: postgresql, transaction, postgresql-9.2, psql

I'm trying to execute an sql script file in a single transation. The file contains includes for some other scripts which in my example create some tables. It looks like this:

```
\include ../tables/table1.cre
\include ../tables/table2.cre
...
\include ../tables/table10.cre
```

I'm executing it using `psql`:

```
psql -X --set AUTOCOMMIT=off --set ON_ERROR_STOP=on -e --single-transaction -d my_db -f my_script.sql
```

The problem is that errors with the include meta command do not cause a transactiopn rollback. e.g. if some of tableX.cre files is missing, any changes before its include will be commited. However, if there's some SQL syntax error, everyting works as expected.

Is it possible to somehow handle include related errors and rollback the active transcation?

I'm using PostgreSQL 9.2.1.

Comment: I would not generally expect psql meta command errors to cause a transaction rollback. I can see why you might in this case, but it's not clear that's the generally correct behaviour. Interesting issue though. You may have more luck raising this one on the pgsql-general mailing list; if you do so, include a link to this post please, but make sure your mailing list post is a complete explanation its self.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I've got an answer at pgsql-general mailing list by Adrian Klaver ([link](http://postgresql.nabble.com/Rollback-on-include-error-in-psql-tp5832192p5832281.html))

There is some kind of unexpected behavior with using both `--set ON_ERROR_STOP=on` and `--single-transaction` options. The `ON_ERROR_STOP` stops the processing, but does not rollback current transaction in case of \include error.

So, the solution for my initial problem will be removing the `single-transaction` option and wrapping explicit BEGIN/COMMIT statements around my main script.